# Can't Remove Polyline on Google Map (Android)

Tags: android, google-maps, polyline

I'm creating app for tracking my step. I use Google MAP API(V2). I drew my step while walking (realtime)
this is my code.

```
    case R.id.btn_location:
            if(polyline != null) {
                polyline.remove();
            }
            if(mStatus == IDLE) {
                map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
                getmyLocation.getmyLocation();
                map.clear();
            }
             break;
case R.id.btn_can_location:

            if (mStatus == RUNNING) {
                mTimer.removeMessages(0);
                mPauseTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                mStatus = IDLE;
                loc_manager.removeUpdates(listener);
             break;
```

//----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------/

```
public class getMyLocation {
  private void getmyLocation() {
        if (loc_manager == null)
            loc_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        long time = 3000; 

        float minDistance = 10;

        loc_manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, minDistance, listener);
        }
    }


private void getmyLocation() {
        if (loc_manager == null)
            loc_manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        long time = 3000; 

        float minDistance = 10;

        loc_manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, time, minDistance, listener);

static class MyLocationManager implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     polyline = map.addPolyline(polylineOptions.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())));
        polylineOptions.width(5);
        polylineOptions.color(Color.RED);

        map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
}
```

Drawing route for realtime is good. But Removing Polyline is not working. 
Helpme

Comment: You can use the 'googlemap.clear();' to clear the google map

Comment: is there any exception or error showing in logcat while trying to remove polyline?

Comment: Yes. Logcat is clear. Error or excetion is no occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your problem is in this area.

```
case R.id.btn_location:
            if(polyline != null) {
                polyline.remove();
            }
            if(mStatus == IDLE) {
                map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                        .getMap();
                getmyLocation.getmyLocation();
                map.clear();
            }
             break;
```

try to initilze the map like this

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

also you need to  implements `OnMapReadyCallback` and do what ever you want inside map ready like this

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    Double lat = Double.parseDouble(latt); // latt is string
    Double lang = Double.parseDouble(lngg); // langg is string
    LatLng location = new LatLng(lat, lang);
    CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(location, 16);
    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(""));
    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(location));
    googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
}
```

and in xml file add this line.

```
<fragment
   android:id="@+id/map"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="@dimen/hundred_thirty_dp"/>
```

> 1 do not get the map object every time when you click the button. just
>   initialize it once in the start
>
> 2 when you call `polyline.remove` you also need to call `map.clear();`

Comment: oh, Thanks for your answer. I initailize the map in onCreate and map is static.
map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
Is it problem...?

Comment: I appreciate your answer. I try to change my code. Thanks

Comment: Sadly It's not work. I realize that the polyline is removed!
When push the button, Polyline and Marker are removed. However Callback the onLocationChanged re-draw the polyline. (before drawing..)
So the polyline is confused which one is first.
I think that LatLng is initialized on buttonDown. but How can i do?

Comment: now that is another problem please explain in question what you want. and ill update the answer.

Comment: Ah.. When finish tracking step, Polylines are display.
I want to remove the line. So i use polyline.remove() method on 'onClick'. And It's work.
But, ReTracking step, draing polyline include before tracking spot. So that looks like removing polyline is not work.

Comment: i dont understand please update your question with code. what you are trying to dothanks.